# How to reload an Application in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a small game which has **New Game** button. There are many variables which need reset when the **New Game** button is pressed. Is there any method which can easily reload the whole application or any alternative to refresh the scene, stage or variables? I just want to bring the application to it's initial stage when It's first loaded.

I went through different topics on internet and read many questions and answers here also, but I there is no easy method to implement it. Most of the answers suggest to reuse the whole code or put the whole code in class and reload it.

Questions reviewed:

- [How to restart a JavaFX application when button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788026/how-to-restart-a-javafx-application-when-a-button-is-clicked)
- [How can you reload or refresh a scene with javafx 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102545/how-can-you-reload-or-refresh-a-scene-with-javafx-1-3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would certainly recommend a clean approach as discussed in the questions you linked.

A quick and dirty way however might be the following:

```
restartButton.setOnAction( __ ->
{
  System.out.println( "Restarting app!" );
  primaryStage.close();
  Platform.runLater( () -> new ReloadApp().start( new Stage() ) );
} );
```

Close the main stage, create a new one and pass it to a new instance of your App. I cannot make any guarantees about the memory behavior of this hack. Use it carefully.

Full example: https://gist.github.com/bugabinga/ce9e0ae2328ba34133bd

Comment: Thanks, 2 years later, this has really helped in implementing a `debug` toggle switch.  I agree with your "use it carefully" caveat!

Comment: Kool :) definitly let us now when this blows up ;P

Answer (score 0):

for reload application you must create new instance of your main class and call
the start method of it with stage parameter.for example

```
restartButton.setOnAction(e->{yourAPP app=new yourApp();
app.start(yourStage);});
```